# Why paintComponent doesn't work?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I'm having issues with this code. For some reason, `paintComponent(Graphics g)` simply doesn't work and there doesn't seem to be an answer how to force it to. This is my code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Robotron extends JFrame
{

    public Robotron ()
    {
        //add(this); This one gave me an error
        setSize(800, 600);
        new TestFrame();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {

        new Robotron();

    }
```

and this is my TestFrame class that has the paintComponent function:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestFrame extends JPanel
{
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
         g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
         g.fillRect(100, 100, 10, 30);
         System.out.println("Abdullah Paint");

     }


    public TestFrame()
    {
        setFocusable(true);        
        repaint();        

    }


}
```

What can I do in order to make paintComponent actually play. What I get in the end is just an empty JFrame, with no running of the System.out.println thingy.

Thanks a whole lot, been tackling this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding anything to the JFrame, because of this

```
//add(this);
```

Here, you were trying to add the component to itself, which is not going to fly.

Instead, you need to add the TestFrame instance to the Frame.

```
    add(new TestFrame());
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Ah okay, it is added to the Frame thingy itself... that helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the panel to the frame:

```
public Robotron ()
{
    //add(this); This one gave me an error
    setSize(800, 600);
    add(new TestFrame());
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you need to add the panel to the frame:

```
public Robotron() {

    add(new TestFrame());
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

As *not* mentioned by others, you need to call `super.paintComponent(g)` the first thing in your overridden method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 10, 30);
    System.out.println("Abdullah Paint");
}
```

**Notes:**

- Don't call `repaint()` in the constructor. At best it does nothing.
- Don't call `setSize(...)` for the frame, instead call `pack()`. You will need to override the `getPreferredSize` method in your panel for this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary to write "super" preceding the paintComponent method. Nor the override thing. Using, at the moment, just the setsize as it does seem to work without any issues.

Comment: @TheForgot3n1 If you don't use `super.` before the first call to `paintComponent` you will get an infinite recursion. The `@Override` is just an annotation, but it is highly recommended to use it. `setSize` will work on your screen and resolution, but not on mine and my friends'.